# Make a live USB of your installed ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb

I wonder that whether there is a way of making my own installed ubuntu a live USB. The reason in fact is that I want to make my ubuntu to be used by anybody. After this guy used my ubuntu I do not want to see his garbage on my ubuntu. I want to see my ubuntu how it was looking before I gave it to him. Therefore, I have assumed that it is the best way of avoiding this problem. I am waiting for your any advice.

Thanks...

Comment: Not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use [remastersys](http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/) to make an iso from a set up, running system, then use that to make a liveusb with [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) or some other similar tool. As long as you have a window manager installed, you can use the ubiquity installer to reinstall the saved copy. Remember to use the 'backup' not distribution option.

Alternatively just image the drive before giving someone the system, then reimage back the old install.